# building glm model using sparkr in windows but it is very slow and getting error while executing R code

Tags: r, apache-spark, glm, sparkr

Data set is large contain 30 columns and 200000 records.I'm building glm model using sparkr but model execution taking so much time and getting error also.. How to reduce model building time using Sparkr and resolve this error given below.Please give me suggestions to improve this code.

R Code: 
Set Spark Home

```
Sys.setenv(SPARK_HOME="C:/spark/spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7")
```

set library path

```
.libPaths(c(file.path(Sys.getenv("SPARK_HOME"),"R","lib"), .libPaths()))

Sys.setenv(JAVA_HOME="C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_71")
```

loading SparkR library

```
library(SparkR)
library(rJava)

sc <- sparkR.session(enableHiveSupport = FALSE,master = "local[*]",appName = "SparkR-Modi",sparkConfig = list(spark.sql.warehouse.dir="file:///c:/tmp/spark-warehouse"))
sqlContext <- sparkRSQL.init(sc)
spdf <- read.df(sqlContext, "C:/Users/prasann/Desktop/V/bigdata11.csv", source = "com.databricks.spark.csv", header = "true")
showDF(spdf)
```

glm model

```
md <- glm(NP_OfferCurrentResponse ~., family = "binomial", data = spdf)
```

Error :  (model execution is very slow and getting error)

```
> md <- glm(NP_OfferCurrentResponse ~., family = "binomial", data = spdf)
Error in invokeJava(isStatic = TRUE, className, methodName, ...) : 
java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed: lapack.dppsv returned 226.
at scala.Predef$.assert(Predef.scala:170)
at org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.CholeskyDecomposition$.solve(CholeskyDecomposition.scala:40)
at org.apache.spark.ml.optim.WeightedLeastSquares.fit(WeightedLeastSquares.scala:140)
at org.apache.spark.ml.regression.GeneralizedLinearRegression$FamilyAndLink.initialize(GeneralizedLinearRegression.scala:340)
at org.apache.spark.ml.regression.GeneralizedLinearRegression.train(GeneralizedLinearRegression.scala:275)
at org.apache.spark.ml.regression.GeneralizedLinearRegression.train(GeneralizedLinearRegression.scala:139)
at org.apache.spark.ml.Predictor.fit(Predictor.scala:90)
at org.apache.spark.ml.Predictor.fit(Predictor.scala:71)
at org.apache.spark.ml.Pipeline$$anonfun$fit$2.apply(Pipeline.scala:149)
at org.apache.spark.ml.Pipeline$$anonfun$fit$2.apply(Pipeline.scala:145)
at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
at scala.c
```

Comment: Anybody is there to help....

Comment: You could provide a sample of the data which produces this error, to make it reproducable.